# bash script to apply ncrcat on multiple files based on cycle number

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I have a simulation model where I can run a simulation in multiple parts, where for each part output is generated with an increasing cycle number. Output files may look like the following:

```
a.000.nc   b.000.nc  c.000.nc
a.001.nc   b.001.nc  c.001.nc
a.002.nc   b.002.nc  c.002.nc
```

To concatenate these files, I use nco, more specifically the record concatenator `ncrcat`. I used to do this manually like the following for each file name (`a` through `c`):

```
ncrcat a.00{0..2}.nc a.nc
```

How would I go about writing a bash script that performs the ncrcat command on all files and concatenates all files with increasing cycle number (so `a.000.nc`, `a.001.nc` and `a.002.nc` to `a.nc`; next file would be `b.000.nc`, `b.001.nc`, `b.002.nc` to `b.nc`)? I got as far with `egrep`, etc. to extract which cycle numbers are present in an `ls` output, but do not know how to extract the file name.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you determine "_all parts that belong together_"? Please [edit] your question to include this information

Comment: I edited the post. So in the end all files with the same prefixes (a, b or c) should include all correspoding cycle numbers (a.00{0..2}.nc to a.nc, b.00{0..2}.nc to b.nc etc).

Comment: Do you know beforehand that you have `a*` and `b*` and `c*`, or are you saying that you need to discover this?

Comment: Are those `.nc` files POSIX text files or something else that requires you to run a specialized command `ncrcat` on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of files like this (the ones from your example, plus all numbers from `000` to `100` for `a`):

```
$ ls
a.000.nc  a.007.nc  a.014.nc  a.021.nc  a.028.nc  a.035.nc  a.042.nc  a.049.nc  a.056.nc  a.063.nc  a.070.nc  a.077.nc  a.084.nc  a.091.nc  a.098.nc  c.001.nc
a.001.nc  a.008.nc  a.015.nc  a.022.nc  a.029.nc  a.036.nc  a.043.nc  a.050.nc  a.057.nc  a.064.nc  a.071.nc  a.078.nc  a.085.nc  a.092.nc  a.099.nc  c.002.nc
a.002.nc  a.009.nc  a.016.nc  a.023.nc  a.030.nc  a.037.nc  a.044.nc  a.051.nc  a.058.nc  a.065.nc  a.072.nc  a.079.nc  a.086.nc  a.093.nc  a.100.nc
a.003.nc  a.010.nc  a.017.nc  a.024.nc  a.031.nc  a.038.nc  a.045.nc  a.052.nc  a.059.nc  a.066.nc  a.073.nc  a.080.nc  a.087.nc  a.094.nc  b.000.nc
a.004.nc  a.011.nc  a.018.nc  a.025.nc  a.032.nc  a.039.nc  a.046.nc  a.053.nc  a.060.nc  a.067.nc  a.074.nc  a.081.nc  a.088.nc  a.095.nc  b.001.nc
a.005.nc  a.012.nc  a.019.nc  a.026.nc  a.033.nc  a.040.nc  a.047.nc  a.054.nc  a.061.nc  a.068.nc  a.075.nc  a.082.nc  a.089.nc  a.096.nc  b.002.nc
a.006.nc  a.013.nc  a.020.nc  a.027.nc  a.034.nc  a.041.nc  a.048.nc  a.055.nc  a.062.nc  a.069.nc  a.076.nc  a.083.nc  a.090.nc  a.097.nc  c.000.nc
```

You can do:

```
for f in *.nc; do echo ${f//\.*}; done | sort | uniq | 
    while read prefix; do echo ncrcat "$prefix".*nc "$prefix".nc; done
```

That produces this output:

```
ncrcat a.000.nc a.001.nc a.002.nc a.003.nc a.004.nc a.005.nc a.006.nc a.007.nc a.008.nc a.009.nc a.010.nc a.011.nc a.012.nc a.013.nc a.014.nc a.015.nc a.016.nc a.017.nc a.018.nc a.019.nc a.020.nc a.021.nc a.022.nc a.023.nc a.024.nc a.025.nc a.026.nc a.027.nc a.028.nc a.029.nc a.030.nc a.031.nc a.032.nc a.033.nc a.034.nc a.035.nc a.036.nc a.037.nc a.038.nc a.039.nc a.040.nc a.041.nc a.042.nc a.043.nc a.044.nc a.045.nc a.046.nc a.047.nc a.048.nc a.049.nc a.050.nc a.051.nc a.052.nc a.053.nc a.054.nc a.055.nc a.056.nc a.057.nc a.058.nc a.059.nc a.060.nc a.061.nc a.062.nc a.063.nc a.064.nc a.065.nc a.066.nc a.067.nc a.068.nc a.069.nc a.070.nc a.071.nc a.072.nc a.073.nc a.074.nc a.075.nc a.076.nc a.077.nc a.078.nc a.079.nc a.080.nc a.081.nc a.082.nc a.083.nc a.084.nc a.085.nc a.086.nc a.087.nc a.088.nc a.089.nc a.090.nc a.091.nc a.092.nc a.093.nc a.094.nc a.095.nc a.096.nc a.097.nc a.098.nc a.099.nc a.100.nc a.nc
ncrcat b.000.nc b.001.nc b.002.nc b.nc
ncrcat c.000.nc c.001.nc c.002.nc c.nc
```

Assuming that is correct, remove the `echo` and run the command again toa ctually concatenate the files.

#### Explanation

- `for f  in *.nc; do ...; done`:  iterate over all files (and directories, if any are present) ending in `.nc`.
- `echo ${f//\.*};`: remove everything after the first `.`. This will just print out the prefixes `a`, `b` and `c`.
- `sort | uniq`: keep only one of each prefix.
- `while read prefix; do ...; done`: iterate over each prefix.
- `ncrcat "$prefix".*nc "$prefix".nc`: run `nrcat` on all filenames starting with this prefix and ending in `.nc`, giving `$prefix.nc` as the outpufile.

Comment: `for f in *.nc; do echo ${f//\.*}; done | sort | uniq` could be implemented without a loop as `printf '%s\n' *.nc | cut -d. -f1 | sort -u` and the subsequent loop using its output `while read prefix; do echo ncrcat "$prefix".*nc "$prefix".nc; done` could be implemented without a loop as `xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c 'echo ncrcat {}.*nc {}.nc'`. With different input file names the versions without a loop would be more robust, in this case they'd just be faster.